# Get Posts of accounts User is Following w/ acts_as_follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using acts_as_follower to allow users to follow each other within my application. I'm wondering how I can retrieve the posts of the users they follow? I currently have built a solution, but it doesn't show the posts in order that they were created and it can't be paginated with will_paginate. Suggestions? My code below is how I'm currently going about it in the pages controller to render the feed on the homepage.

```
@posts = current_user.following_users.includes(:posts).collect{|u| u.posts.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")}.flatten
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a sql expert, but try this:

```
following_ids = current_user.following_users.map(&:id)
Post.where(user_id: following_ids).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
```

2 queries. You can certainly do it with one and joins, but I like the simplicity

Comment: Yep. That worked! Thanks. I know a lot of people have been wondering the same thing. I thought maybe there would have been a method that came with the gem to achieve this.

Comment: interesting. I'll look into the gem more over break and maybe fork it to make this easy. I need following for a project coming up anyway